# How set the position of a FloatingActionButton for a ListView in flutter?

Tags: listview, flutter, floating-action-button

I'm searching for a solution to set the position of a FAB in a StatelessWidget with a ListView. I have a Widget with a Column, that contains two children (ListView and FAB).
The first issue is the position of the FAB and the second issue is the background of the column. The second column hides the buttom of the ListView.

How can I hover the FAB over the ListView?

[image]

```
class ListView extends StatelessWidget {
  final List<Bouquet> bouquets;

  ListView({@required this.bouquets});

  final ScrollController _controller = new ScrollController();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Column(
      children: [
        Expanded(
            child: ListView(
          children: getChildren(),
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          controller: _controller,
        )),
        Container(
          color: Colors.red,
          child: Row(children: [
            Expanded(
                child: FloatingActionButton(
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
              onPressed: () => _controller.animateTo(0,
                  duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
                  curve: Curves.easeInOut),
              mini: true,
            ))
          ]),
        )
      ],
    );
  }

  List<Widget> getChildren() {}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the `Stack` widget you can put widget over widget. My suggestion:

```dart
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Stack(
      alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
      children: [
        ListView(
          children: getChildren(),
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(0.0),
          controller: _controller,
        ),
        FloatingActionButton(
          child: Icon(Icons.arrow_upward),
          onPressed: () => _controller.animateTo(0,
          duration: Duration(milliseconds: 500),
          curve: Curves.easeInOut),
          mini: true,
        )
      ],
    );
  }
```

Comment: Thx a lot. That is the solution.